# consider the `fork` program given, how many times does the following program print hello?

Tags: c, process, fork

> Please, consider the `fork` program given  below:

How many times does the following program print hello?

```
main(int argc, char **argv) {
 int i;
 for (i=0; i < 3; i++) {
 fork();
 printf("hello\n");
 }
}
```

Total “hello” messages = 2 + 4 + 8 = 14 ([see question-1 at page-5](https://www.cs.rutgers.edu/~pxk/416/exam/old/exam1-review-2014-s.pdf)).

---

How many times does the following program print hello?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
main()
{
int i;
for (i=0; i<3; i++)
fork();
printf("hello\n");
}
```

Total “hello” messages = 8 ([see question-4 at page-5](https://www.cs.rutgers.edu/~pxk/416/exam/old/exam1-review-2011-s.pdf)).

It seems to me both program are same. Why are explanation/answer is different?

> Can you explain, please?

Comment: The printf is outside the for loop's block scope.

Comment: It's hard to see because of poor indentation, but look closely at what the `for` loop encompasses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here `printf("hello\n”);` statement in first program is inside the `for` loop.

```
for (i=0; i < 3; i++) {
 fork();
 printf("hello\n”);
 }
```

And,  `printf("hello\n”);` statement in second program is outside the `for` loop.

```
for (i=0; i<3; i++)
fork();//after semicolon printf is outside the for loop's block scope.
printf("hello\n");
```

That is difference between both given code.